# iOS Sending POST using SSL (HTTPS)

Tags: php, ios, ssl, https

i quite new to those things, and i need some advices
I use PHP and JSON on a dedicated server to communicate with my iOS App, i am working on a chat for example, and i use the php : GetMyMessage.php and POST Method: $_POST['myID']="239" $_POST['secure_key']="1HSQFKJHkshfdgjssdfnk"
and it return a JSON with all my message.
But by reading an article on a blog, i found out an easy method to sniff the packet from the iphone.
And it's so easy to read the post header that it frightened me.
Do the use of https with an ssl certificate, prevent "hackers" to sniff the packets and read the headers ? is this enough secured ? Do it change anything to my Objective-C Code ? I just have to change the http to https and it will be automaticly encrypted by iOS ? 
Really big thanks in advance, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Objective-C, yes, just change to `https`. Your server needs to support `https` and it needs to have a properly sourced certificate (you'll have problems if the certificate isn't trusted by a root authority). I assume what you're trying to achieve is to prevent people from snooping on other peoples messages, in which case this should be enough.

Comment: Thanks very much, some futher question:
Does it make request delay longer ? is there in your opinion a best certificat provider for mobile ?
Thanks in advance again, and sorry for my english.

Comment: Technically, yes, it makes it slower (because it has to encrypt the data) but that shouldn't be a concern. The certificate has nothing to do with mobile, it's entirely to do with the server. There are no preferences but your hosting account may already have https (ssl) you can bundle on.

Comment: ok thanks because i saw on some Certificate comparation "Mobile compatible" on some and not on other. i will call my provider assistance to have their advice.
Thanks you!